# how to get a geocode api address pattern .fromaddress?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-apps-script

Im using geocode api from google maps and Im trying to use the answer from server to fill up a form, the problem is, it's not a pattern of object, the result[0].address_components sometimes return 4, 5 and 7 obj and I can`t to know with one is the city, country etc, there is some way to get like result.something.street, result.something.city etc?

```
 else{
     Geocode.fromAddress(cep).then(
        response => {
        const { lat, lng } = response.results[0].geometry.location;
        console.log(response.results[0].address_components);
        console.log(response);
      },
      error => {
        console.error(error);
      }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to filter the object

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ergec/fhnbt39u/)

```
function getValue(adress_components, component_name) {
  return adress_components.filter(c => c.types[0] == component_name)[0].long_name
}
var components = response.results[0].address_components;
console.log(getValue(components, 'street_number'));
console.log(getValue(components, 'locality'));
console.log(getValue(components, 'country'));
console.log(getValue(components, 'postal_code'));
```